# Slash between the base url and path is missing when redirected

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have a website in production. I have the ssl certificate working correctly. For the example.com or http://example.com or www.example.com i have a redirect to https://example.com. All good here. The problem is that when i go to www.example.com/sample1/ i get redirected to https://example.comsample1/ (see the slash missing....). It only happens with that slash because if i go to www.example.com/sample1/sample2/ i get redirected to https://example.comsample1/sample2/.

I have no idea whats going on.

here is my httacces file... not sure if its really working....

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: What if you rewrite this to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 [R,L]`?

Comment: How this is a Python/Django question exactly ??? You'd have the exact same issue with PHP or even static html files. Please only use relevant tags, thanks (nb: fixed).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No it does not work.... (yes i have restarted apache)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers sorry it's my first question on the site...

Comment: Make sure to also clear your browser history between tests, or open a new private window … redirects get cached quite heavily by some browsers.